# How to add search functionality in Endlessscrollview(Lazy Loading) in recyclerview android

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

We are using Lazy loading in Recyclerview but we are not able to add search functionality in lazy loading, kindly suggest any solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: Whether you loading the data from API call or from local device?

Comment: Loading the data from API call @HariNJha

Comment: Since all items are not loaded, you have to get support from API. Implement a search api, which will get input string from android and returns the result. you can clear all items in the adapter and add new items. You can also implement pagination for search results too if the count is more.

Comment: add the search related data, along with the position in a map. query your search from that map and use index to display the relevant items